# Sql: Find sum of column from second table using date from first table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, statistics

I've been struggling to build a query that calculate the sum of column called 'TIDAL_VOLUME' with respect to date value that's coming from another table.

Please see the content of the Table_1:
[image: Content of the Table_1]

Please see the content of the Table_2:
[image: Content of the Table_2]

Note: TIDAL_VOLUME might have NULL as well.

Now, the start time for O2_Device value 'Endotracheal tube' is '2013-08-06 08:10:05' for same HADM_ID and SUBJECT_ID. and end time is whenever new O2_Device value comes in. In this case which is 'Nasal cannula'. Which means start time for 'Endotracheal tube' is '2013-08-06 08:10:05' and end time is '2013-08-06 10:15:05' for HADM_ID = 1 and SUBJECT_ID = 100.

Using that start time and end time criteria, I have to look for TIDAL_VALUE in Table_2. In this example it's 700, 800. Ans for TIDAL_VOLUME is 1500.

Please see the resultant output look like this:
[image: Required Output]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of images add text or make a dbfiddle example and also show yourt Select statement as **text**

Comment: Getting time ranges from different rows is complicated and inefficient. Is there any way you could add the end time to the same row?

Comment: @Barmar, I'm also trying to solve this by  adding END_DATE column. If I'm able to do that then It'll be easier. Whichever way is easier, I'll go with that in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add `End_Time` to the first table, you can use `BETWEEN` when you join the tables.

```
SELECT t1.HADM_ID, t1.Subject_ID, t1.ChartTime, SUM(t2.tidal_volume) AS tidal_volume
FROM Table_1 AS t1
JOIN Table_2 AS t2 
    ON t1.HADM_ID = t2.HADM_ID 
        AND t1.Subject_ID = t2.Subject_ID 
        AND t2.ChartTime BETWEEN t1.ChartTime AND t1.End_Time
GROUP BY t1.HADM_ID, t1.Subject_ID, t1.ChartTime
```